# JavaMail setDebug(true)

Tags: java, stream, jakarta-mail

How can I `setDebug(true)` on a JavaMail session but capture the stream and use it in my logging framework? (Short of downloading the source, changing the method to accept a stream as a parameter, recompiling it, ...)

More generally, is there a standard way in Java to "hijack-and-redirect" generic stream output in this fashion? Note that System.out may be already polluted with other output and I have no idea how to "filter" that...

Answer (score 11):

You can link a PrintStream to a ByteArrayOutputStream, tell to JavaMail to use your PrintStream, do the JavaMail stuff and finally, dump the the content of the ByteArrayOutputStream to your favorite logger.

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        try {
           if (MAIL_DEBUG) {
                logger.info("JAVAMAIL debug mode is ON");
                mailSession.setDebugOut(ps);
                mailSession.setDebug(true);  
            }
            ...
            transport.close();
            if (MAIL_DEBUG) {
                logger.info(os);
            }
        }
          finally {
            ps.close();
            os.close();
        }
```

Comment: Once I set it to stream and it keeps the debug in the logger,it doesn't show in console anymore. Is there a way to also made sure the setdebug is shown at console at same time?

Comment: @daredevil,  maybe in the `if (MAIL_DEBUG)` add a  `System.out.println(os.toString());` ?

Comment: I did that. And I tried to run it on command prompt as a jar file, it didn;t output to console. weird? Where is `MAIL_DEBUG` declared? I didn't use an if statement.

Comment: `MAIL_DEBUG` is simply a flag that you define to control the debugging mode of your program. It's not part of JavaMail. Maybe try with `System.err.println(os.toString());`

Comment: I added this `System.out.print("Email sent successfully\n");` and it managed to print this out on command prompt but not the os.tostring

Comment: From what I tested, adding `println(os.tostring())` only prints this statement "DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.0" to console, not everything